# bootstrap auto-hint/validation on form field types

Tags: html5, jquery

It seems that Bootstap has a 'field type' validation, that it performs automatically.

Is there a way I can turn that off, OR, maybe better, pass messages to that along with making it work on plain txt field for 'required'???

```
<input type="email" class="form-control"...>
```

pops up a well formated pointy box with "please enter an email"

However - I wrote custom stuff to alert on other text fields being required, I cannot find docs on this and it seems heavy handed to only effect "types" that have some formatting, and not allow the same formatting for other validation.

any help is much appreciated

Comment: It's not a bootstrap functionality, it's HTML5. The message that pops out is from the browser. You can see a list of the new types [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bootstrap functionality, the new input types are part of the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#states-of-the-type-attribute). You can see an example of they working [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp).

The message that pops out is from the browser, and you can see that it changes from one browser to another, as you can see below (sorry for the messages in portuguese):

**Google Chrome**:

[image: Chrome email validation]

**Firefox**:

[image: Firefox email validation]

Note that the new input types are not widely supported by the browsers, so you should not rely just on them.

Comment: ah - thank you - and that explains why I could not find anything in the code, or docs.